# Gaussian distribution, maximum entropy and the heat equation.

Tags: probability, entropy, heat-equation

Consider the Gaussian distribution on $\mathbb{R}$ with mean $m$ and variance $t=\sigma^2$. This has the explicit density

$$ f(x,m,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{(x-m)^2}{2t}} $$

The Gaussian distribution has many characterizations, and two of them are the following:

1. The Gaussian distribution maximizes entropy amongst all the distributions on $\mathbb{R}$ with mean $m$ and variance $t$.
2. The density $f(x,m,t)$ provides a solution of the heat equation. More precisely, consider the differential equation
   $$ \begin{cases} \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} &= \frac{\partial^2 u }{\partial x^2}  \quad \text{ for } x\in \mathbb{R},t>0 \\
   u(x,0) &= \delta_m(x) 
    \end{cases} $$ 
   where $\delta_m$ is the Dirac concentrated at $m$. Then the function $u(x,t)=f(x,m,2t)$ is a solution of this differential equation.

I would like to know whether there is a reason (intuitive or more formal) why the solution of the two problems (maximum entropy distribution and heat equation) is the same. Of course, an explanation is that we can solve explicitly both problems and the solution happens to be the same, but I wonder whether there is a more conceptual reason for this.

Comment: crossposted: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/280186/gaussian-distribution-maximum-entropy-and-the-heat-equation/280190#280190